# How do I create ~/.aws/credentials file for Up on MAC

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, telegram

I'm developing a bot for Telegram and I am using [Up](https://up.docs.apex.sh/#aws_credentials) to create a Lambda function for AWS. The problem is that when I want to create the function I get an error saying:

> Error: Cannot find credentials, visit https://up.docs.apex.sh/#aws_credentials for help.

How do I create the ".aws" folder and the "credentials" file? Under what folder will this be saved? Is it in the same folder I created my bot?

This is on MAC.

Answer (score 22):

After installing the AWS CLI for Mac, type `aws configure` to initialize the credentials file for the first time.

Answer (score 7):

If you have homebrew you can install awscli like this:

```
brew update
brew install awscli
```

And then use the following to configure your aws with you access id and token:

```
aws configure
```

Answer (score 5):

1. First, you need to install AWS CLI for OSX using the following link. Refer the documentation for [Install the AWS Command Line Interface on macOS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html) for more details.
2. Then you need to create AWS Programmatic Access Credentials (After creating a AWS IAM User) and download the credentials. For this you need to go to the IAM section of AWS Web Console. Refer the documentation for [Understanding and Getting Your Security Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html) for more details.
3. Then configure the credentials using the shell commands. Refer the documentation [Configuring the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install AWS CLI in your mac OS from link below:
   [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux-mac.html#cliv2-linux-mac-install][1]
2. Verify installation. Change to aws instead of aws2 incase you are using version-1

```
$ aws2 --version
```

3. Configure

```
$ aws2 configure
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your CLI before you can use it.

From 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

"Quick Configuration
For general use, the 'aws configure'  command is the fastest way to set up your AWS CLI installation."